# org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler

Tags: listener, spring-rabbit

```
Spring with Rabbitmq Integration application i am facing some issue with 

>Listener.exception
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message

Endpoint handler details:

>Method [public void com.pn.pg.rabbit.ProducerController.receiveMessage(com.pn.pg.vo.SMSVO)]
Bean [com.pn.pg.rabbit.ProducerController@2223d7e3]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:129)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:779)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:702)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:95)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:186)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1227)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:683)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1181)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1165)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1500(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:95)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1367)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 

can any one help me to resolve this.
thanks in advance
configuration in consumer side
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="localhost" port="5672" username="guest" password="guest"/>

    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>
   <rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" message-converter="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
  <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter">
        <property name="classMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultClassMapper">
            <property name="defaultType" value="com.pn.springrabbitmq.controller.SMSVODuplicate" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

   <!-- <rabbit:template id="rabbitMessagingTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" /> -->

 <bean id="rabbitListenerContainerFactory"   class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory">
        <property name="connectionFactory"  ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5"/>
        <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
        <property name="prefetchCount" value="10"/>
        <property name="defaultRequeueRejected" value="false"/>
        <!-- <property name="messageConverter" value="listenerAdapter"/> -->
       <!--  <property name="messageConverter" value="jsonMessageConverter"/> -->
    </bean> 
    <rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory">
    <rabbit:listener ref="rabbitListenerContainerFactory" queue-names="queue.newstatus" />
    </rabbit:listener-container>
**Listening Code**

 @RabbitListener(queues = "queue.newstatus")
      public void recieveMessage(SMSVODuplicate status) {
        System.out.println("Email Queue in Consumer ::"+"name::"+status.getStatus());
}
```

In above code iam getting some exception like org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException.iam able to produce message to queue with Producer Application ,in case of Listening in Reciever Application facing issue.
can any one help me to resolve thanks in advance

Comment: You need to show your configuration, listener bean, and the full stack trace.

Comment: Don't put this in comments. Delete these and edit the question instead.